Showing three different pictures on map series using ArcGIS Pro
I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.6.
I have set up a layout for a map series based on a hosted feature layer with pictures as attachments. In this layout, there are 3 frames to show up to 3 different pictures attached to an entity. I would like to know how to set those frames to each show a different picture and not the same one as it is by default.
My photos don't always have the same name (1455a.jpg; uiahehhr.jpg; photo1.jpg) as the file name is random (photos taken on the field with Field Maps with different mobile phones).
I've read some topics about how to do it if your attachments have a regular name (photo1.jpg; photo2.jpg) but nothing for random names.
Here you can see my layout with 3 different image frames. And the 3 different settings for those layouts.

Frame 1 is just set as dynamic and the attachment.
Frame 2 is set as a dynamic, attachment and filtered by the name of the 2nd attachment.
Frame 3 is set as dynamic and attachment


Rename attachments inside table to make them 'regular'. Simple field calculation

As the layer is hosted I have no access to the attachments table.

If you put the full photo paths in fields in the map series source layer as they are needed or change throughout the series. The series can update image elements dynamically based on the path in the associated field. Within image element properties window select dynamic (as opposed to static path/url), the drop down for dynamic is fields in the map series and the image in field for single feature will display when that feature prints within the series.

Thank for the idea. I have no direct access to the photo path in the hosted feature layer. The only way to get the URL of the attachment is to open it from the pop up window of ArcGis Pro.

Per these docs you should be able to use an Arcade expression to specify an image. And Arcade does have an Attachements function you can use to get an array of Attachement objects for a given feature. So for first image you could write an expression that calls that function and then grabs the element at index 0, for the next image do the same but grab the element at index 1, etc.
Caveats:

I'm not sure if your Arcade expression can simply return the Attachement object directly (hopefully?), or if you would need use its properties to manually build a URL string
I'm not sure if you can expect the array returned by Attachements() to be consistently sorted ... probably though?
I'm not sure how error handling works with Arcade, e.g. if you try to grab an element at an index that doesn't exist

